# Font-locking for text inside org-mode COMMENT blocks

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, comment

While other sorts of #+BEGIN ... #+END blocks seem to get font-locking applied to them (potentially changing foreground and background colours etc.), #+BEGIN_COMMENT ... #+END_COMMENT blocks do not.  Is there any way to have font-locking apply to these?